# BluetoothDevice is not fetching available devices

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am trying to make an app which lists all the devices which is already paired and once user clicks search then it will search for new devices.

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.bluetoothfinder;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> bluetoothDevices;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    Button buttonFind;
    TextView textView;

    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i("actions", intent.getAction());
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED)) {
                textView.setText("Finished");
                buttonFind.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        bluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bluetoothDevices);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        buttonFind = findViewById(R.id.buttonFind);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        for (BluetoothDevice d : devices) {
            bluetoothDevices.add(d.getName());
        }
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (bluetoothDevices.size() == 0) {
            bluetoothDevices.add("no devices");
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

        buttonFind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                textView.setText("Searching...");
                buttonFind.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am not able to get the available devices nor I am able to find `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND` in logs.
I have added the necessary permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Has you enabled the permission in the setting? even though you already declare that the app need those permission, it's not enabled by default. You need to ask for permission as well.

Comment: It worked! Can you tell me what permissions should be asked to user and what permissions would be enabled by default?

Comment: You always have to check if the permission is granted and ask the system to grant the permission to your app. Have a look at this to see how: https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions

Comment: That is not what I asked. For eg permissions like internet would be given to app by default whereas permission like location should be explicitly given by user. I asked to list all the permissions which user should grant to app

Comment: It's on Android doc page: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#types